# mysql ranking based on sum of values

Tags: mysql

having a mysql table with multiple records belonging many different users like this:

### id                   score

1  ,    50

1  ,    75

1   ,   40

1,  20

2    ,  85

2     , 60

2     , 20

i need to get the rank of each id but after finding the sum of their score;

the rank should be the same if the total score for each player is the same.

this gives me the total for each player:

```
select id,sum(score) as total from table_scores group by id order by total desc;
```

is it posssible to find the sum like above and use it to rank the players in one query?

Comment: Did you test your query? If not, do it. If yes, then you can see it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rank rows using variables:

```
select
  id, total,
  CASE WHEN @l=total THEN @r ELSE @r:=@r+1 END as rank,
  @l:=total
FROM (
  select
    id, sum(score) as total
  from
    table_scores
  group by
    id
  order by
    total desc
) totals, (SELECT @r:=0, @l:=NULL) rank;
```

Please see it working [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2dcfc/1).

Comment: yes i get the rankings but the ids with similar totals do not have the same rank..like 3 id have 444 so i expect them to tie in rank

Comment: @gordon if they have the same total they will get the same rank http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2060f/1 is this what you are after?

Comment: yes. that's it .al just modify a bit to remove the extra column.thanks

Comment: @Gordon Think should award this answer, that this guy solved your problem :) that would be nice thing to do when somebody solve your problem... GL

Answer (score 2):

Something big missing from the accepted answer. The rank needs to be bumped after a tie. If you've got 2 tied for 3rd place, there is no 4th place.

The following query is an adjustment of the accepted SQL to account for this and reset the rank variable (@r in the query) to match the row value. You can avoid the extra addition in the CASE/WHEN but initializing @row to 1 instead of 0 but then the row value is off by 1 and my OCD won't let that stand even if row number is not valuable.

```
select
  id, total,
  CASE WHEN @l=total THEN @r ELSE @r:=@row + 1 END as rank,
  @l:=total,
  @row:=@row + 1
FROM (
  select
    id, sum(score) as total
  from
    table_scores
  group by
    id
  order by
    total desc
) totals, (SELECT @r:=0, @row:=0, @l:=NULL) rank;
```

Answer (score -1):

i find one more way to this problem... This one is based on JOIN clause

```
SET @rank = 0;

SELECT t1.id, t1.score, t2.rank 
       FROM (SELECT id, SUM(score) as score 
             FROM table_scores GROUP BY id ORDER BY score Desc) AS t1
INNER JOIN
      (SELECT x.score, @rank:=@rank + 1 as rank FROM 
              (SELECT DISTINCT(SUM(score)) AS score 
               FROM table_scores 
               GROUP BY id ORDER BY score DESC) AS x) AS t2
ON t1.score = t2.score
```

Here is SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2dcfc/16

P.S. it's interesting to see there is more then one way to solve a problem...